# Dancer2 stringifies everything on the server but not locally

Tags: json, perl, serialization, ubuntu-16.04

I run identical code (my Dancer2 app) locally on my mac's plenv's v5.26.2 but when I run the app (whether with plackup or starman or proxied behind Apache, with our without SSL, or requesting locally on each location with Curl) the server-running instance is stringifying everything in the responding payloads.

`"custid": "5000",` on the ubuntu 16 server (system perl v5.22.1 - libraries are same versions as my local instance)

`"custid": 5000,` on my local machine.

In my `config.yml` I got (among other things, but this is the only `engines` block)

```
content_type: "application/json"
serializer: "JSON"

engines:
  serializer:
    JSON:
      pretty: 1
```

The data itself does come from a DB but my local machine and the server's `DBIx::Class` respectively connect to the same remote (not local to the ubuntu) mysql server with the same ResultSources..

One thing I can think of is the server to be using `Cpanel::JSON::XS` and something is "touching" the results as strings before they get to the serializer, but I'm not sure how to check which JSON library is actually used on each running app instance.

So - 
How come I get different stringification with the same code?
How to check what JSON library is used on each instance?

Comment: You can look at `%INC` to see what's loaded. That should give a hint as to which JSON module it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it seems it was the `DBD::mysql` that was installed. I had 4.033 (and I had no `mysql_config`  so probably that kept it back) and there seems there are a few changes since that might be the cause but not sure:

Perhaps one of:

[Numeric conversions in perl which led to overflow/underflow was ignored
    even when mysql strict mode was enabled](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/DBD-mysql#L196)

[Use correct format in printf instead of casting variable types](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/DBD-mysql#L215)

Or any of the changes around having `mysql_config` available. 
Either way big ups to the maintainers!
Also this server was upgraded from 14.04 LTS which of course changed system perl things. (But I don't recall noticing the stringification on 14.04)

Comment: You can run your own Perl pretty easily if you want to, or ship your own dependencies. Dancer2 is fully fatpackable if you don't use XS stuff.

Answer (score 2):

[Dancer2 uses](https://metacpan.org/source/CROMEDOME/Dancer2-0.207000/lib/Dancer2/Serializer/JSON.pm#L26) [JSON::MaybeXS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS) to decide which module to load. You can use the [`->JSON` class method](http://perl%20-MJSON::MaybeXS%20-E%20'say%20JSON::MaybeXS-%3EJSON') on that to ask it which one it loaded.

```
$ perl -MJSON::MaybeXS -E 'say JSON::MaybeXS->JSON'
```

Comment: Damn they both use the same `Cpanel::JSON::XS` which is good in the sense that I know something must be touching the DB result. I wonder if it's to do with the mysql driver

Comment: That's possible. Or the database version. Or the JSON module version.